# Arduino + C# . I try to convert a string to int and I have an error about DateTime type

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino, serial-communication

Maybe I am a little bad at telling whats going on but I will try my best (sorry about my english).

Arduino code:

```
 //Setup message bytes
    byte inputByte_0;
    byte inputByte_1;
    byte inputByte_2;


int pin = 9;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()> 2) 
  {
    inputByte_0 = Serial.read();delay(10);    
    inputByte_1 = Serial.read();delay(10);      
    inputByte_2 = Serial.read();delay(10);   
  }
  //Check for start of Message
  if(inputByte_0 == 4)
  {       
       //Detect Command type
       switch (inputByte_1) 
       {
         case 8://Set Port Identification Number, this case is only to find the correct port in order to connect.
             switch (inputByte_2)
            {
              case 16:
                Serial.print("I'M ARDUINO");
                break;
              case 32: 
                  Serial.print(digitalRead(x)); // Here I send via serial the value of x pin. 1/0 and receive in C# as a String. The "receiving" is handled by a class named "communicator" which I show it below.
                  break;

            }
        } 
        //Clear Message bytes
        inputByte_0 = 0;
        inputByte_1 = 0;
        inputByte_2 = 0;
  }
}
```

So here is the class "communicator" which gets the messages from Arduino.

```
namespace testtemp
{
    public class communicator
    {
        public string port = "";
        static SerialPort currentPort;
        public Boolean connect(int baud, string recognizeText, byte paramone, byte paramtwo, byte paramthree)
        {
            try
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
                buffer[0] = Convert.ToByte(paramone);
                buffer[1] = Convert.ToByte(paramtwo);
                buffer[2] = Convert.ToByte(paramthree);

                int intReturnASCII = 0;
                char charReturnValue = (Char)intReturnASCII;
                string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                foreach (string newport in ports)
                {
                    currentPort = new SerialPort(newport, baud);
                    currentPort.Open();
                    currentPort.Write(buffer, 0, 3);
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    int count = currentPort.BytesToRead;
                    string returnMessage = "";   // Here I see that the message is a STRING so I wonder what is wrong.
                    while (count > 0)
                    {
                        intReturnASCII = currentPort.ReadByte();
                        returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII);
                        count--;
                    }

                    currentPort.Close();
                    port = newport;
                    if (returnMessage.Contains(recognizeText))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        public string message(byte paramone, byte paramtwo, byte paramthree)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
                buffer[0] = Convert.ToByte(paramone);
                buffer[1] = Convert.ToByte(paramtwo);
                buffer[2] = Convert.ToByte(paramthree);
                currentPort.Open();
                currentPort.Write(buffer, 0, 3);
                int intReturnASCII = 0;
                char charReturnValue = (Char)intReturnASCII;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                int count = currentPort.BytesToRead;
                string returnMessage = "";
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    intReturnASCII = currentPort.ReadByte();
                    returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII);
                    count--;
                }
                currentPort.Close();
                return returnMessage;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error";
            }}}}
```

And now I have the main class where I want to use that value from Arduino, the value from x pin. That value is provided by a call of the function: comport.message(4,8,32);

This is the code:

```
namespace testtemp
{
    public partial class tempreaderform : Form
    {
        public tempreaderform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        communicator comport = new communicator();
        Boolean portConnection = false;
       Int32 red_light1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            if (comport.connect(9600, "I'M ARDUINO", 4, 8, 16))
            {
                label1.Text = "Connection Successful - Connected to  "+comport.port;
                portConnection = true;
                tempreader.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Not connected . . . ";
                portConnection = false;
                tempreader.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void tempreader_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)// Here I have a timer that is called every 100ms to read that 
        {
            red_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));// Here I get this error:"when converting a string to datetime parse the string to take the date before putting each variable"
I have nothing to do with datetime type. I don't understand why I get this error. 

            label3.Text = comport.message(4, 8, 32); When I put that value in a label everything works fine. I see that value oscilating from 0 to 1 and viceversa.
            // Here I have a timer that is called every 100ms to read that value.
        }

        private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics rectangle1 = groupBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Graphics ellipse1 = groupBox1.CreateGraphics();

            Brush color = new SolidBrush(Color.DimGray);

            Brush red_on = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Brush red_off = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkRed);

            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);


            if (label3.Text == "1")
            {
                ellipse1.FillEllipse(red_on, 123, 78, 24, 24);
            }
            else ellipse1.FillEllipse(red_off, 123, 78, 24, 24);
             // Here I want to color an ellipse depending on the value of red_light1 and doesn't work because I never see "red_light1" as true.
}}}
```

I am sorry for long question and maybe is not the best explained question. I reply as fast as I can if somebody doesn't understand something in my question/code.

Comment: _I try to convert a string to int and I have an error about DateTime type_ o.O

Comment: Read all before just commenting the title.

Comment: Can you paste your Exception stack trace

Comment: Is the line "red_light1 = Convert.ToIntcomport.message(4, 8, 32);" a copy/paste error? Cause there are definitely missing brackets around that "comport.message". Also shouldn't it be Int32?:  Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u5rop0yyt765rm/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @LocEngineer that is just a copy/paste error. Sorry for that. In the program the brackets are in the right way. I try with Int32 and come back with feedback. Also in my code was Int32 but when I posted the question I made some edits and forgot to write Int32.

Comment: Please, please try to make your subsequent questions more to the point. This is too much to go through and is actually incorrect.
Now the actual error has nothing to do with DateTime, this is simply VS's help message, i.e. it's just a tip. what you have is a format exception. That is, the string you entered to `Convert.ToInt32` is not an integer. I'll guess it has something to do with the `return "Error";` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
red_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));
```

method `comport.message()` returns a string which is then converted into an integer. This works when the string is e.g. "123", but your Arduino sketch is passing binary data (see `Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII)`). Byte codes 48 to 57 map to the decimal numbers 0 to 9 and can be converted. Other byte codes however cannot be converted to an integer.

In other words, `Convert.ToInt32("123")` works, but `Convert.ToInt32("abc")` does not work.

When you are looking for an easy way to communicate with Arduino boards from Windows devices, I suggest taking a look at [SolidSoils4Arduino](https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino). It's a library supporting serial, Firmata and I2C communication. It also offers methods to automatically find serial port connections and it has support for Mono too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, actually the problem was from the arduino code, because I send to serial the returned value from function "digitalRead" which returns HIGH or LOW/TRUE or FALSE which I think are boolean. I resolve the situation by changing Serial.print(digitalRead(pin)) to if(digitalRead(pin) == HIGH) Serial.print("1");

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning to suspect that the error lies here:

```
returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII);
```

Why do you convert To char here? That can have side effects if intReturnAscII is not what you'd expect. Also, your returnMessage is a string, so treat it as one.  Use

```
returnMessage = returnMessage + intReturnASCII.ToString();
```

instead.
Also this:

```
int intReturnASCII = 0;
char charReturnValue = (Char)intReturnASCII;
```

is completely unnecessary as you never do a thing with charReturnValue. You just assign NULL and then let it linger.